# Animating list items that are partially hidden or at the end of the currently visible views in a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, animation, android-listview

I'm currently implementing my own custom listview. I idea is that a longclick on a list item will scale the surrounding visible views to a smaller value scale and leave the the current view normal, whilst expanding a view below the current selected view. Once the user touches anywhere around the selected view, it will scale everything back to normal.

Unfortunately, there's an issue whereby the last view maybe partially hidden during the scale animation and so doesn't scale back to normal. So when you try to gain focus to the rest of the Listview by touching outside the selected list item, it remains a smaller scale.

I've tried a few approaches, from using ViewTreeObserver to storing the positions of the list items to make sure that they get scaled, but nothing has worked. Below is my custom listview:

```
public class ZoomListView extends ListView implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {


    private static final String TAG = ZoomListView.class.getName();
    private int _xPos;
    private int _yPos;
    private int _pointerId;
    private Rect _viewBounds;
    private boolean _isZoomed;
    private OnItemClickListener _listner;
    private OnItemFocused _onItemFocusedLis;
    private int _expandingViewHeight = 0;
    private int _previousFocusedViewHeight;
    public interface OnItemFocused {

        /**
         * This interface can be used to be notified when a particular item should be disabled, or is currently not focused
         * @param position
         */
        public void onItemOutOfFocus(int position, boolean status_);
        public View onItemFocused(View focusedView_, int listViewPosition_, long uniqueId_);
    }

    public ZoomListView(Context context_) {
        super(context_);
        init(context_);
    }

    public ZoomListView(Context context_, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context_, attrs);
        init(context_);

    }

    public ZoomListView(Context context_, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context_, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context_);

    }

    @Override
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        if(!(listener == null)){
        _listner = listener;
        }
        super.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
    }

    private void init(Context context_){
        setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setOnItemDisableListener(OnItemFocused listener_){
        _onItemFocusedLis = listener_;
    }

    private void scaleChildViews(long rowId_, int itemPos_, float scale, boolean shouldEnable){

        if (_isZoomed) {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }

        int firstVisiblePosition = getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int pos = pointToPosition(_xPos, _yPos);
        int positionOrg = pos - firstVisiblePosition;
        scaleAllVisibleViews(positionOrg, scale, shouldEnable);
    }

    private void scaleAllVisibleViews(final int clickedItemPosition_, final float scale_, final boolean shouldEnable_) {
        Animation scaleAnimation;
        if(_isZoomed){
            scaleAnimation = getZoomAnimation(1f, 0.8f, 1f, 0.8f);
        }else{
            scaleAnimation = getZoomAnimation(0.8f, 1f, 0.8f, 1f);
        }
        int firstVisiblePosition = getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int pos = i;
            if (_isZoomed) {

                if (getAdapter().getItemId(clickedItemPosition_) != getAdapter().getItemId(pos)) {
                    scaleView(pos, scale_, shouldEnable_, scaleAnimation);
                }else{
                    displayExpandingView(pos, clickedItemPosition_);
                }

            } else {
                    View view = getChildAt(pos);

                    View viewToShow =  _onItemFocusedLis.onItemFocused(view, pos, getAdapter().getItemId(clickedItemPosition_));

                    if(viewToShow != null){
                        viewToShow.setVisibility(GONE);
                    }
                    scaleView(pos, scale_, shouldEnable_, scaleAnimation);

            }
        }
    }

    private void displayExpandingView(int position_, int clickedItemPosition_){
        View view = getChildAt(position_);
        if(view != null){
            Log.v(TAG, "view is valid");
            View viewToShow =  _onItemFocusedLis.onItemFocused(view, position_, getAdapter().getItemId(clickedItemPosition_));

            viewToShow.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            Animation flip = new CyclicFlipAnimation(50f);
            flip.setDuration(500);
            viewToShow.startAnimation(flip);

            if(_expandingViewHeight <= 0){
                viewToShow.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                _expandingViewHeight = viewToShow.getMeasuredHeight();
                Log.v(TAG, "expanding view hieght is + " + _expandingViewHeight);
            }
        }
    }


    private Animation getZoomAnimation(float fromX_, float toX_, float fromY_, float toY_){
      Animation  scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(
                fromX_, toX_,
                fromY_, toY_,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        scaleAnimation.setDuration(500);
        return scaleAnimation;
    }

    private void scaleView(int position_, float scale_, boolean shouldEnable_, Animation animation_){
        View view = getChildAt(position_);
        if (view != null) {
            view.startAnimation(animation_);
            if (_onItemFocusedLis != null) {
                _onItemFocusedLis.onItemOutOfFocus(position_, shouldEnable_);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        _isZoomed = true;
        scaleChildViews(l, i, 0.8f, false);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                _xPos = (int) event.getX();
                _yPos = (int) event.getY();
                _pointerId = event.getPointerId(0);

                if (_isZoomed) {
                    if (!_viewBounds.contains(_xPos, _yPos)) {
                        _isZoomed = false;
                        scaleChildViews(1, 1, 1f, true);
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                int position = pointToPosition(_xPos, _yPos);
                int childNum = (position != INVALID_POSITION) ? position - getFirstVisiblePosition() : -1;
                View itemView = (childNum >= 0) ? getChildAt(childNum) : null;
                if (itemView != null) {
                    _viewBounds = getChildViewRect(this, itemView);
                }

                break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }


    private Rect getChildViewRect(View parentView, View childView) {
        final Rect childRect = new Rect(childView.getLeft(), childView.getTop(), childView.getRight(), childView.getBottom() + _expandingViewHeight);
        if (parentView == childView) {
            return childRect;
        }

        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) childView.getParent();
        while (parent != parentView) {
            childRect.offset(parent.getLeft(), parent.getTop());
            childView = parent;
            parent = (ViewGroup) childView.getParent();
        }
        return childRect;
    }

}
```

Any idea's on what maybe wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue I ended up adding a ACTION_MOVE case statement in my onTouch method. So as long as the list items were focused again, when the list performed a move i.e. scrolled the list item, the remaining list items are restored to their original size. To achieve this you need to maintain a map/collection of id's that correspond to your list items and iterate over them once the user scrolls.

Heres the full somwhat functiong implementation:

```
package com.sun.tweetfiltrr.zoomlistview;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.ScaleAnimation;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.sun.tweetfiltrr.animation.CyclicFlipAnimation;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 */
public class ZoomListView extends ListView implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {


    private static final String TAG = ZoomListView.class.getName();
    private int _xPos;
    private int _yPos;
    private int _pointerId;
    private Rect _viewBounds;
    private boolean _isZoomed;
    private OnItemClickListener _listner;
    private OnItemFocused _onItemFocusedLis;
    private int _expandingViewHeight = 0;
    private int _previousFocusedViewHeight;
    private OnScrollListener _onScrollListener;
    private boolean _shouldPerformScrollAnimation;
    final private Map<Long, PropertyHolder> _itemIDToProperty = new HashMap<Long, PropertyHolder>();
    private long _currentFocusedId;


    public interface OnItemFocused {

        /**
         * This interface can be used to be notified when a particular item should be disabled, or is currently not focused
         * @param position
         */
        public void onItemScaleOut(int position, View view, boolean status_);
        public void onItemRestore(int position, View view, boolean status_);
        public View onItemFocused(View focusedView_, int listViewPosition_, long uniqueId_);
    }

    public ZoomListView(Context context_) {
        super(context_);
        init(context_);
    }

    public ZoomListView(Context context_, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context_, attrs);
        init(context_);

    }

    public ZoomListView(Context context_, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context_, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context_);

    }


    private void init(Context context_){
        setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setOnItemDisableListener(OnItemFocused listener_){
        _onItemFocusedLis = listener_;
    }

    private void scaleChildViews(long rowId_, int itemPos_, float scale, boolean shouldEnable){

        if (_isZoomed) {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }

        scaleAllVisibleViews(shouldEnable);
    }


    private void scaleAllVisibleViews(final boolean shouldEnable_) {
        final ListAdapter adapter = getAdapter();
        Animation scaleAnimation;
        if(_isZoomed){
            scaleAnimation = getZoomAnimation(1f, 0.6f, 1f, 0.6f);
        }else{
            scaleAnimation = getZoomAnimation(0.6f, 1f, 0.6f, 1f);
        }

        int count = getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                applyAnimation(i, adapter, shouldEnable_, scaleAnimation);
            }
    }


    private void applyAnimation(int position_, ListAdapter adapter_, boolean shouldEnable_, Animation animation_){
        if (_isZoomed) {
                if (_currentFocusedId != adapter_.getItemId(position_)) {
                    scaleView(position_,  shouldEnable_, animation_);
                }else{
                    displayExpandingView(position_, adapter_);
                }
        }else{

            if(_currentFocusedId != getAdapter().getItemId(position_)){
                scaleView(position_,  shouldEnable_, animation_);
            }else{
                View view = getChildAt(position_);
                View viewToShow =  _onItemFocusedLis.onItemFocused(view, position_, getAdapter().getItemId(position_));

                if(viewToShow != null){
                    viewToShow.setVisibility(GONE);
                }
            }

            _itemIDToProperty.remove(getAdapter().getItemId(position_));
        }
    }

    private void displayExpandingView(int position_, ListAdapter adapter_){
        View view = getChildAt(position_);
        if(view != null){
            View viewToShow =  _onItemFocusedLis.onItemFocused(view, position_, adapter_.getItemId(position_));
            viewToShow.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            Animation flip = new CyclicFlipAnimation(60f);
            flip.setDuration(1000);
            viewToShow.startAnimation(flip);

            if(_expandingViewHeight <= 0){
                viewToShow.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                _expandingViewHeight = viewToShow.getMeasuredHeight();
            }

        }
    }

    private Animation getZoomAnimation(float fromX_, float toX_, float fromY_, float toY_){
      Animation  scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(
                fromX_, toX_,
                fromY_, toY_,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.7f);
        scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        scaleAnimation.setDuration(500);
        return scaleAnimation;
    }

    private void scaleView(int position_,  boolean shouldEnable_, Animation animationScale_ ){
        View view = getChildAt(position_);
        ListAdapter adapter = getAdapter();
        long id = adapter.getItemId(position_);
        view.startAnimation(animationScale_);

        PropertyHolder holder = _itemIDToProperty.get(id);

        if (holder == null) {
            holder = new PropertyHolder((int) view.getTop(), (int) (view.getBottom()));
            _itemIDToProperty.put(id, holder);
        }

        int h = view.getHeight();
        if (_isZoomed) {
            view.animate().translationYBy((h * 0.5f)).setDuration(500).start();
            if (_onItemFocusedLis != null) {
                _onItemFocusedLis.onItemScaleOut(position_, view, shouldEnable_);
            }
        } else {
            view.animate().translationYBy(-(h * 0.5f )).setDuration(500).start();
            if (_onItemFocusedLis != null) {
                _onItemFocusedLis.onItemRestore(position_, view, shouldEnable_);
            }
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        _isZoomed = true;

        int firstVisiblePosition = getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int pos = pointToPosition(_xPos, _yPos);
        int positionOrg = pos - firstVisiblePosition;

        _currentFocusedId = getAdapter().getItemId(positionOrg);
        scaleChildViews(l, i, 0.8f, false);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                _xPos = (int) event.getX();
                _yPos = (int) event.getY();
                _pointerId = event.getPointerId(0);

                if (_isZoomed) {
                    if (!_viewBounds.contains(_xPos, _yPos)) {
                        _isZoomed = false;
                        scaleChildViews(1, 1, 1f, true);
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                int position = pointToPosition(_xPos, _yPos);
                int childNum = (position != INVALID_POSITION) ? position - getFirstVisiblePosition() : -1;
                View itemView = (childNum >= 0) ? getChildAt(childNum) : null;
                if (itemView != null) {
                    _viewBounds = getChildViewRect(this, itemView);
                }

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (!_isZoomed) {
                    animateRemaining();
                }
            break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private void animateRemaining(){
        if(!_itemIDToProperty.isEmpty()){
        for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++){
           long id =  getAdapter().getItemId(i);
           PropertyHolder n = _itemIDToProperty.get(id);
            if(n != null){

                if(_currentFocusedId != getAdapter().getItemId(i)){
                    scaleView(i,  true, getZoomAnimation(0.6f, 1, 0.6f, 1f));
                }else{
                    Log.v(TAG, "not translating for " + getAdapter().getItemId(i)+ " for id " + _currentFocusedId);
                }
                _itemIDToProperty.remove(id);
            }
        }
        }
    }


    private Rect getChildViewRect(View parentView, View childView) {
        final Rect childRect = new Rect(childView.getLeft(), childView.getTop(), childView.getRight(), childView.getBottom() + _expandingViewHeight);
        if (parentView == childView) {
            return childRect;
        }

        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) childView.getParent();
        while (parent != parentView) {
            childRect.offset(parent.getLeft(), parent.getTop());
            childView = parent;
            parent = (ViewGroup) childView.getParent();
        }
        return childRect;
    }

    private class PropertyHolder{
        int _top;
        int _bot;

        private PropertyHolder(int top_, int bot_){
            _top = top_;
            _bot = bot_;

        }

    }


}
```

It's far from perfect but its a starting point.